# Rebuilding corrupt slave by copying mysql folder

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication

Rebuilding an existing slave from a master using cold-copying of /var/lib/mysql, would this be the proper process/order? Anything missing?

1. master `mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS\G` (take notes)
2. slave `mysql> STOP SLAVE;`
3. Shut down master and slave mysqld
4. Move existing slave:/var/lib/mysql out of the way
5. Copy master:/var/lib/mysql to slave:/var/lib/mysql
6. Start master mysqld
7. Start slave mysqld
8. slave
   `mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='masterserver',

   -> MASTER_USER='replicationusername',

   -> MASTER_PASSWORD='replcationpassword',

   -> MASTER_LOG_FILE='logfilefromshowmasterstatus',

   -> MASTER_LOG_POS=positionfromshowmasterstatus;`
9. slave `mysql> start slave;`

Comment: There will be some time between "SHOW MASTER STATUS" and shutting down mysqld.  Might I suggest using "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;" then "SHOW MASTER STATUS;" (Take notes).  FLUSH tables will make sure all changes are written to disk and with read lock will make sure the database does not change afterward.

Comment: Here are step by step instruction how to do this with minimal downtime using Linux LVM snapshots. http://www.juhavehnia.com/2015/05/rebuilding-mysql-slave-using-linux-lvm.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest referring to a following link:

[MySQL  MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual  16.1.1 How to Set Up Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

Other pieces to add to the mix:

step 6.5 Check permissions after moving files

Step 7 - restart slave with mysqld_safe --skip-slave-start &

Answer (score 0):

1.- Stop master and slave mysqld.

2.- On slave move /var/lib/mysq/ to someplace else.

3.- Copy /var/lib/mysql from master to slave.

4.- Check permissions on slave.

5.- On slave (/etc/my.cnf) set --skip-slave-start

6.- Start master and slave mysqld

7.- On slave point to the new master binlog file just created, on position 4.

8.- start slave io_thread, then see if everything is okay

9.- start slave sql_thread and wait the slave to get up to date.

That's it.